# Uploading file to GDrive by terminal/command line

Tags: command-line, terminal, google-drive-api

I'm developing a program for a platform that does not have support libraries to upload or download files from Google Drive.
So I need to send the Socket commands in hand.
But I find it difficult to achieve.

My program will send files type .txt, jpg, .html and others.

I will have to send and download these files from the command line. I've tried but I was not successful ...

First to get a valid token I'm using this link that the user will open in a browser and copy the token inside my program to modify their files:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=profile&response_type=code&state=security_token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&client_id=165834794520-tit58jbii1u8itv8q8urjlda1tobsvf1.apps.googleusercontent.com

Apparently this part works correctly.

But when I use the token to send a file, it does not work.
I made this command as a test and it does not work!
I've changed the token several times thinking it might be it, but it's not.
Weird.

My files, I will send from the command line so I am not sure which method I should use, SIMPLE or MULTIPART ...
My files are small, but maybe some 5MB pass.

Look what I get in the terminal(raw socket):

```
S: POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
S: Host: www.googleapis.com
S: Authorization: Bearer 4/AABZB61gFY8NqyXxxxxxxxxxxr7CThy1BuDOOGL7aLiRab80
S: Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
S: Content-Length: 167
S: 
S: --foo_bar_baz
S: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
S: 
S: {
S:   "name": "myObject"
S: }
S: 
S: --foo_bar_baz
S: Content-Type: image/jpeg
S: 
S: [JPEG_TEST]
S: --foo_bar_baz--

Return:

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UoolTbsyS_gK21G07sUJrIggzH_ivy1a_KvzvnvhiyqIOYqej8JhNQ1tmZ0KiIlrYjOTejlxXYIoSiTNs3mLiLBWzCb-A
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 249
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 12:51:18 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

The error seems to be wrong Token, but I always get new tokens and it always gives the same error!

Can someone help me???

Comment: It might be worth looking at https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

Comment: Thank you!
But this is a ready library.
Commands will be sent as shown above.
Libraries do not work on my device!
I have to send the commands through a raw socket.
Doing POST at hand.

Comment: I meant for you to read the source code to see how the author deals with with tokens.

Comment: I understand now. But my doubt is the format of the requisition I have to make. The POST format. The token is a part of POST. I need to know the correct structure of the request. I found no example that worked.

Comment: it looks like you have not correctly understood and implemented oauth. The "token" you are using (4/xxxx) looks like an Auth Code, not an Access Token. The best way to see what the OAuth POSTs look like is to use the Google Oauth Playground

Comment: Nice! now work! but i see it: "expires_in": 3600
I can configure to never expires?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
MAX_THREAD_NO=32

runningPids=()
canStartNewBatch=1
sequenceNo=0

# Create remote folder corresponding with the name of the local folder.
#     $1: parentId: remote (gdrive) parent folder id
#     $2: folderName: local folder name need to create in remote parent folder
# Usage:
#     folderId=$( makeRemoteDir <parentId> <folderName> )
function makeRemoteDir () {
    resultPrefix="Directory "
    resultSuffix=" created"
    
    folderId=`gdrive mkdir -p $1 $2`
    folderId=${folderId%"$resultSuffix"}
    folderId=${folderId#"$resultPrefix"}

    echo "$folderId"
}

# Upload the files contained in the local folder to remote folder.
#     $1: remoteFolderId: remote (gdrive) folder id
#     $2: localFolderFullPath: the full path of local folder name need to upload
function uploadFolder () {
    # Do with each item (folder or file) in the folder $2
    for item in $2/*; do
        while [[ ${#runningPids[@]} -ne 0 ]] && [[ canStartNewBatch -ne 1 ]]; do
            removablePids=()

            # Scan every PID in the running PIDs list to see if it finished or not
            for pid in "${runningPids[@]}"; do
                if ! ps -p $pid > /dev/null; then
                    removablePids+=($pid)
                fi
            done

            if [[ ${#removablePids[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
                # Remove finished PID from the runningPids, and allow new PID put in
                for removablePid in "${removablePids[@]}"; do
                    runningPids=( ${runningPids[@]/$removablePid} ) 
                done
                canStartNewBatch=1
            else
                # If no more PID finished yet, then scan again after few delay time
                sleep 0.05
            fi
        done

        canStartNewBatch=1
        # If the item is a file, upload it to remote
        if [[ -f "$item" ]]; then
            #((sequenceNo++))
            #echo "$sequenceNo $item"
            gdrive upload -p $1 "$item" &
            pid=$!
            runningPids+=($pid)
            if [ ${#runningPids[@]} -eq $MAX_THREAD_NO ]; then
                #echo ${#runningPids[@]}
                canStartNewBatch=0
            fi
        fi

        # If the item is a folder, recursive call uploadFolder
        if [[ -d "$item" ]]; then
            # Create sub-folder (with the name equals local folder name) in the remote folder with id equals to parentId, store the
            newFolderId=$( makeRemoteDir $1 $(basename ${item}) )

            # Recursive call upload
            uploadFolder $newFolderId "$item"
        fi
    done
}
```